# When using the train() function with cross-validation train-control, how do you see the model's predictions on the test set?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, machine-learning-model

I'm a beginner trying to learn some basic machine learning techniques.

I want to use leave-one-out cross-validation and the train() function to train a model. My function seems to work as it should. However, I'm not able to see the model's test-set predictions. How would you do this given the following model?

```
# Create custom trainControl: myControl
myControl <- trainControl(
  method = "loocv", 
  verboseIter = TRUE
)

# Fit glmnet model: model
model <- train(
  y ~ ., 
  data,
  method = "glmnet",
  trControl = myControl,
  preProcess = c("center", "scale", "pca")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `savePredictions=TRUE` in `trainControl`:

```
myControl <- trainControl(
  method = "loocv", 
  savePredictions=TRUE
)

model <- train(
  mpg ~ ., 
  data,
  method = "glmnet",
  trControl = myControl,
  preProcess = c("center", "scale", "pca"),
  tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = c(0.1,0.01),lambda = c(0.1,0.01))
)
```

You can look at the predictions using each parameter combination:

```
      pred obs rowIndex alpha lambda Resample
1 22.56265  21        1  0.10   0.10   Fold01
2 22.59835  21        1  0.10   0.01   Fold01
3 22.57767  21        1  0.01   0.10   Fold01
4 22.59717  21        1  0.01   0.01   Fold01
5 22.12174  21        2  0.10   0.10   Fold02
6 22.14886  21        2  0.10   0.01   Fold02
7 22.13080  21        2  0.01   0.10   Fold02
8 22.14667  21        2  0.01   0.01   Fold02
```

I tested 4 combinations of lambda and alpha, so you can see above for each observation that is left out, it's prediction

Comment: Is there a way to save only the "best" prediction (the prediction from the parameter combination that minimizes RMSE) and then add those predicted values as a column in the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own follow-up question in case anyone is interested:

```
myControl <- trainControl(
  method = "loocv"
  savePredictions = "final",
)

model <- train(
  y ~ ., 
  data,
  method = "glmnet",
  trControl = myControl,
  preProcess = c("center", "scale", "pca")
)
data$pred <- model$pred[ , "pred"]
```